# Как сделать такие новости??

Tags: jquery

Добрый день! Как сделать вот такие новости как на сайта 
http://www.bestnews.in.ua/
НА главной страницы типо слайда при навидении на одно из название новостей меняются сами новости?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите сами написать или ищите готовое решение? Если готовое решение, то можете за основу взять [этот плагин](http://landofcoder.com/demo/jquery/lofslidernews/index2.html), хотя аналогов в инете можно найти много. А если самому написать, то алгоритм крайне простой: в одной колонке выводите превьюшки (например списком **ul**), по событию или hover, или mouseover, или любому другому на элементе списка (**li**), меняете контент в основном окне. Даже не знаю, что и добавить. В принципе, ничего не мешает использовать для этих целей [Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) (jQuery UI), только со стилями поиграться.

Comment: Спасибо коротко и ясно!

Answer (score 2):

Еще, как вариант, можно посмотреть как это реализовано на сайте [lostfilm.tv](http://lostfilm.tv/) :

- открываем сайт
- клик правой кнопкой -> исходный код страницы -> 461-я строка -> клик по содержимому атрибута `src`